# Acumatica : Set Initial Label of Button based on initial value of a Field or when field value changes

Tags: c#, customization, acumatica

I am working in Opportunity Customization. I have  custom button that I want to reuse depending on what the user is doing.

The first time through, if they click the button, I will create a folder in Google Drive.

If that has already been done, when they click the button, I will open the GDrive folder previously created in a new browser window. In order to know which action to take, I am using the ExternalRef field.

I want the display name of the button to show what will happen when the user clicks it, so they know what to expect.

However, I cannot change the display name in a Delegate, and I cannot see how to change the value upon initialize.

I guess I need to build a function for that? But it is unclear how to do that from the examples, and I can't find this use case described in the training course.

Here is a stub of my delegate for the custom button:

```
public PXAction<CROpportunity> OpportunityInGDRIVE;
[PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "SETUP QUOTE", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
public virtual void opportunityInGDRIVE()
{
   // I can VIEW the caption, but cannot SET it
    var _Caption = OpportunityInGDRIVE.GetCaption();
    if (Base.Opportunity.Current.ExternalRef.ToUpper().Contains("GDRIVE"))
     {
        // GOOGLE API info gets inserted here...
        // I WANT to SET Caption here, but not allowed
        Base.Opportunity.Current.ExternalRef = "GDRIVE";
        Base.Opportunity.UpdateCurrent();
    }
    else
    {
        // send to google drive... this is a place holder
        var redirectException =
           new PXRedirectToUrlException("https://www.cepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/BuildersNoSmartHomes_large-1100x650.jpg",
               PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.New, "Acumatica.com");
        throw redirectException;
    }
}
```

So, I need to know how to:

A) Change label display in initialize based on the initial value of ExternalRef

B) Change Label display when I come back from creating folder in Google Drive (although I am changing the value of ExternalRef again, so maybe that can be handled in a change attribute delegate for that field? IDK.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the caption inside the RowSelected event handler of the CROpportunity (main DAC).

```
 public virtual void _(Events.RowSelected<CROpportunity> e, PXRowSelected baseHandler)
    {
        baseHandler?.Invoke(e.Cache, e.Args);

        CROpportunity row = e.Row;
        if (row == null) return;
        
        this.OpportunityInGDRIVE.SetCaption((Base.Opportunity.Current.ExternalRef.ToUpper().Contains("GDRIVE")) ? "GDRIVE" : "DROPBOX");
       
    }
```

Comment: When is the RowSelected event raised? And, can I call it from another function?

Comment: The event is raised whenever the record/row is selected/inserted/updated/deleted. This is basic Acumatica knowledge: I would highly advise to go through Application Developer Training Course. You cannot call it, but raise it from another method, but I am not sure why would you need it: when you come back from your method, that changes the ExternalRef, the record is selected again and the label is updated.

Comment: Well, the point is that I would want it to update the label when it first comes in (before a user interacts with the screen at all) -- To be clear I am not doing this from CR3040PL, I am doing it from OP000392 -- so I'm not sure what row refers to... Also, when I tried your code, I get error: 'OpportunityMaint' does not contain a definition for 'OpportunityInGDRIVE' and no accessible extension method. There is no typo, that doesn't show in Base.

Comment: you are right, I've tried with another action, from base and forgot to remove Base. before OpportunityInGDRIVE. I've edited the answer to fix that. CR3040PL is just a generic list. OP000392 is opport. ID, but you but getting an error from OpportunityMaint (CR304000). So yes, I've extended the OpportunityMaint and set the caption inside RowSelected. Try the updated code and see if it works (the RowSelected is called 2 times before anything is displayed, and then 2 times before record update and 2 times after row update: therefore it should change upon update of ExternalRef without any confusion

Comment: Did you try the proposed solution? If so, don't forget to accept the answer so others will know. If it's not working, please give more details: what is the page ID that you want to customize? What is the initial (no previous action) label? What is that function that you are talking about?

Comment: I have not had a chance to try it yet. I got bogged down on another aspect of the overall project right now. I will try it and report back.

Comment: This worked though I needed to add a try-catch around Base.Opportunity.Current.ExternalRef since it can be null, and then it threw an exception. Having a "rowSelected" event on a single record still isn't intuitive to me. But, whatever... Glad to have something that works!

Comment: try-catch is not good handling in this case, because exceptions are expensive and RowSelected is heavily used. You can use ?. - Elvis operator - 
Base.Opportunity.Current.ExternalRef?.ToUpper()

Comment: Also change Base.Opportunity.Current with row: this.OpportunityInGDRIVE.SetCaption(row?.ExternalRef?.ToUpper().Contains("GDRIVE"))   and/or you can also change the first if and don't get the exception, like this: if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row?.ExternalRef)) return;